# "Cannot read property of undefined at am4themes..." while formatting chart.plotContainer via theme in AmCharts4

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, amcharts

I want to fill the plot area of my XYChart via a theme; however I receive the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'background' of undefined at am4themes_myTheme`

I referenced [this documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-themes/) in trying to come up with an answer.

**This does what I want, but not via a theme**: page.html

```
var chart = am4core.create("viz", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.plotContainer.background.fill = am4core.color('green');
```

**This is what I tried for my custom theme:** 
myTheme.js

```
function am4themes_bi(target) {
    if (target instanceof am4charts.Chart) {
        target.plotContainer.background.fill = am4core.color('green');
    }
}
```

How can I change my theme function so that it turns the plot area green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `plotContainer` isn't defined yet going by the error message. You'll want to a check to see if `target.plotContainer` is defined first before attempting to set it:

```
function am4themes_bi(target) {
    if (target instanceof am4charts.Chart) {
      if (target.plotContainer !== undefined) { 
        target.plotContainer.background.fill = am4core.color('green');
      }
    }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ffda76159414cf2d65d4652c2d44e1ad?editors=1010)

Comment: Works great! Is this happening because it is creating Chart objects multiple times, but not always creating a plotContainer? Or is it a timing issue?

Comment: I think it's a timing issue, but I'd have to confirm with the devs.